# Assets not able to create good gif/png thumbnail

Tags: assets, thumbnails

I'm using assets to take care of images 
In the view of assets all thumnails of png and gif's don't show only the jpg's

[image: Assets printscreen]

I tried to see if it would work with the EE file upload and there it works fine

[image: EE image upload]

Is there a setting I should enable that i have missed or is this a bug?

EDIT: i forgot to say that when viewing the image of png or jpg with their tag in the template then they show correctly

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you send an email to support@pixelandtonic.com referencing this question and include one of the images that don't render for you?

I can't reproduce this on my local Assets install.

Thanks,
Andris

Comment: This was caused by .htaccess killing all index.php requests - fixed by adding an exception for index.php requests with ACT get parameter set.

Comment: ah, that would have been a hard one to pinpoint so glad Andris was able to help out and get to the root cause. :)

Comment: Can you clarify what your .htaccess looks like now?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth checking that the /system/expressionengine/cache/ directory is writable (777 permissions) and that you have the GD/GD2 library installed. Place a phpinfo.php file in the site root and view it's output to check.

Comment: I have checked everything is writable to 777 and i see the assets/thumbs but nothing in there... also this is the phpinfo gives me this : GD Support  enabled, GD Version bundled (2.0.34 compatible)